# Queueing sessions for Appium

Tags: appium, selenium-grid

I'm trying to create a simple device farm (prioritize Android for now) with Selenium Grid and Appium (v1.13.0) and I need some help with queueing test runs for Appium.

For example I have 2 Appium nodes (running with 2 android emulators) on the hub, I want the test runs will queue for the node, if there're 2 test runs point to a node, then the later test run will have to wait for the first one to finish before starting on that node.

Currently, with my setup, the later test run will interrupt the first one (force terminate) instead of waiting.

Below is my json file for a node, different node will have different `deviceName` and `port`

```
{
    "capabilities":
    [
        {
            "browserName":"Nexus 5X",
            "platform":"Android",
            "version":"9",
            "maxInstances":1,
            "deviceName":"Nexus 5X"
        }
    ],
    "configuration":
    {
        "cleanUpCycle":2000,
        "timeout":30000,
        "proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "maxSession":1,
        "url":"http://127.0.0.1:4741/wd/hub",
        "host":"127.0.0.1",
        "port":4741,
        "register":true,
        "registerCycle":5000,
        "hubPort":4444,
        "hubHost":"127.0.0.1"
    }
}
```

To my understanding, Selenium Grid does support sessions queueing, but Appium doesn't (or not that I known of). When I try to start another Appium session the same node, the session does actually have to wait for the previous Appium session to close before starting. So, to achieve what I want, I must have something in the middle to start the Appium session on a node when a test run start and close it when the test run end.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Or is there a Appium configuration that support this that I don't know of?

Answer (score 0):

- As per my understanding, you need to run two test case in two
  different devices with-out perform any manual action.
- For that, you need to manage Appium start-stop action by
  programmatically, this is simpler way and most used full way.
- With that way, you can manage two or more than two devices.

Reference code is following for Manage Appium start-stop action by programmatically.

```
def service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder() .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node")) .withAppiumJS(new File("/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js")) .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1") .usingPort(port as int) .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.ROBOT_ADDRESS, udid as String) .withArgument(AndroidServerFlag.BOOTSTRAP_PORT_NUMBER, ((port as int) + 2) as String) .withArgument(SESSION_OVERRIDE) .withLogFile(new File("build/${device}.log")));

service.start();
```

Reference Link: https://www.seleniumeasy.com/appium-tutorials/how-to-start-appium-server-programmatically